# Fontification by AUCTeX is great, but font locking for ConTeXt code, any idea?

Tags: latex, themes, font-lock

I wasn't sure where to post this question, but I count on the `Emax` community when it comes to font-locking and fontification.

We all know that AUCTeX is the way to go when writing a document in LaTeX, part of it due to the fontification this mode provides for the default LaTeX macros. But consider this MWE written with [ConTeXt](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page):

```
\setuplayout
  [header=2\lineheight,
   headerdistance=\lineheight]

\setupbackgrounds[header][text][frame=off, bottomframe=on]

\setupheader[style=bold]
\defineframed[headerframed]
             [frame=off,
              align=middle,
              width=fit]
\setupheadertexts[\headerframed{C \\ D}]
\setupheadertexts[\headerframed{A \\ B}][\headerframed{E \\ F}]
\starttext
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

In ConTeXt the `\starttext` and `\stoptext` are the equivalents of `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands. Yet, Emacs doesn't show any fontification for many of the commands in ConTeXt. I am using `moe-theme`.

[image]

How to enable that? is there any known package to do that for you? Do I need to setup that manually command by command? If yes, how?

Comment: AUCTeX doesn't have great ConTeXt support because none of the active developers use it.  Help on improving it with high-quality code is much welcome!

Comment: sorry to hear that, but until one of the developers start using it, isn't there a way to font lock custom commands under AUCTeX so that one can add those of ConTeXt? If yes, any documentation in that direction?

Comment: See https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2015-04/msg00003.html